# python function not recurving properly (adding nodes to graph)

Tags: python, graph, recursion, nodes

I'm having a rare honest-to-goodness computer science problem (as opposed to the usual how-do-I-make-this-language-I-don't-write-often-enough-do-what-I-want problem), and really feeling my lack of a CS degree for a change.

This is a bit messy, because I'm using several dicts of lists, but the basic concept is this: a Twitter-scraping function that adds retweets of a given tweet to a graph, node-by-node, building outwards from the original author (with follower relationships as edges).

```
for t in RTs_list:
g = nx.DiGraph()
followers_list=collections.defaultdict(list)
level=collections.defaultdict(list)
hoppers=collections.defaultdict(list)
retweets = []
retweeters = []
try:
    u = api.get_status(t)
    original_tweet = u.retweeted_status.id_str
    print original_tweet
    ot = api.get_status(original_tweet)
    node_adder(ot.user.id, 1)
    # Can't paginate -- can only get about ~20 RTs max. Need to work on small data here.
    retweets = api.retweets(original_tweet)
    for r in retweets:
        retweeters.append(r.user.id)
    followers_list["0"] = api.followers_ids(ot.user.id)[0]
    print len(retweets),"total retweets"
    level["1"] = ot.user.id
    g.node[ot.user.id]['crossover'] = 1
    if g.node[ot.user.id]["followers_count"]<4000:
        bum_node_adder(followers_list["0"],level["1"], 2)
    for r in retweets:
        rt_iterator(r,retweets,0,followers_list,hoppers,level)      
except:
    print ""

def rt_iterator(r,retweets,q,followers_list,hoppers,level):
q = q+1
if r.user.id in followers_list[str(q-1)]:
    hoppers[str(q)].append(r.user.id)
    node_adder(r.user.id,q+1)
    g.add_edge(level[str(q)], r.user.id)
    try:
        followers_list[str(q)] = api.followers_ids(r.user.id)[0]
        level[str(q+1)] = r.user.id
        if g.node[r.user.id]["followers_count"]<4000:
            bum_node_adder(followers_list[str(q)],level[str(q+1)],q+2)
            crossover = pull_crossover(followers_list[str(q)],followers_list[str(q-1)])
        if q<10:
            for r in retweets:
                rt_iterator(r,retweets,q,followers_list,hoppers,level)
    except:
        print ""
```

There's some other function calls in there, but they're not related to the problem. The main issue is how Q counts when going from a (e.g.) a 2-hop node to a 3-hop node. I need it to build out to the maximum depth (10) for every branch from the center, whereas right now I believe it's just building out to the maximum depth for the first branch it tries. Hope that makes sense. If not, typing it up here has helped me; I think I'm just missing a loop in there somewhere but it's tough for me to see.

Also, ignore that various dicts refer to Q+1 or Q-1, that's an artifact of how I implemented this before I refactored to make it recurve.

Thanks!

Comment: Please reindent your code. Also, don't use bare except clause, never...

Comment: "bare" except is only because I can't fetch some twitter IDs due to them being protected -- doesn't affect the outcome, I just want them skipped.

Comment: @serilain just figure out which error the twitter ID being protected produces, and just catch that one. In addition to what eblume and bruno mentioned, bare except clauses also it also makes it much harder to debug if something is messing up (since you never see any exceptions)

Comment: @serilain : with all the code going on here, you don't have _any_ idea of what exception could be raised (and currrently totally silenced by your bare except clause). I tell you this from experience: _never_ assume whatever about which exception will (or will not) pop. For you information, Python's `sys.exit()` is implemented by raising a `SysExit` exception. Using a bare except in a loop means you won't be able to cleanly exit the program when it's in that loop (and if it happens to be an infinite loop then `kill -9` is your last resort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by "the center" but I think you want something like this:

```
def rt_iterator(depth, other-args):
    # store whatever info you need from this point in the tree
    if depth>= MAX_DEPTH:
        return
    # look at the nodes you want to expand from here
    for each node, in the order you want them expanded:
        rt_iterator(depth+1, other-args)
```

Comment: yeah, that looks like the answer I just posted myself! thanks! sorry this was so convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

think I've fixed it... this way Q isn't incremented when it shouldn't be.

```
def rt_iterator(r,retweets,q,depth,followers_list,hoppers,level):
def node_iterator (r,retweets,q,depth,followers_list,hoppers,level):
    for r in retweets:
        if r.user.id in followers_list[str(q-1)]:
            hoppers[str(q)].append(r.user.id)
            node_adder(r.user.id,q+1)
            g.add_edge(level[str(q)], r.user.id)
            try:
                level[str(q+1)] = r.user.id
                if g.node[r.user.id]["followers_count"]<4000:
                    followers_list[str(q)] = api.followers_ids(r.user.id)[0]
                    bum_node_adder(followers_list[str(q)],level[str(q+1)],q+2)
                    crossover = pull_crossover(followers_list[str(q)],followers_list[str(q-1)])
                if q<10:
                    node_iterator(r,retweets,q+1,depth,followers_list,hoppers,level)
            except:
                print ""
depth = depth+1
q = depth
if q<10:
    rt_iterator(r,retweets,q,depth,followers_list,hoppers,level)
```